# Is there a way to determine the important features (weight) for an SVM that uses an RBF kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, libsvm

Using sklearn, I did both a linear kernel SVM and a rbf one. While the rbf gave really great results, I can't determine the important features that the algorithm kept (or used more).

I know that "coef_" does only work for a linear kernel, since for rbf the data space is no longer finite (or at least, it changes [I think]).

Is there a way to actually determine the important features for an RBF kernel SVM ?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  It would be helpful if you would tag your question with the software you are using. It is also a best practice to type out your Three Letter Acronyms (TLA) at the first use in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately not. Although SVMs are often interpreted as transforming your features into a high-dimensional space and fitting a linear classifier in the new space, the transformation is implicit and cannot be easily retrieved.

In fact, SVMs with the RBF kernel behave more like soft nearest neighbours. To see this, denote by $\{x_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^N$ the training data, and $K(.,.)$ the kernel of choice: in this case $K(x,x')=\exp(-\gamma\|x-x'\|^2)$. Then the SVM prediction for an example $x$ takes the form 
$$ \mathrm{sign}\left( 
\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i y_i K(x_i, x) + \rho 
\right), $$
where $\rho$ is the `intercept_` and $\alpha_i$ are the `dual_coef_` in `sklearn` (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svc)). As you can see, the decision function is just a linear combination of training labels $y_i$, where the influence of each training example $x_i$ is determined by its overall importance $\alpha_i$ and its distance from $x$, as given by $K$. Closer points have an exponentially larger effect on the prediction, hence the nearest neighbour analogy.

Coming back to your question: maybe it doesn't make so much sense to think in terms of features for SVMs with RBFs (would you ask about features for nearest neighbours?). You may want to have a look at the most influential data points, though, to get a "template" interpretation of your model.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) maybe you can add that the rbf kernel implicitly transforms your features into a higher dimensional space of ' transformed features' and tries to separate linearly in that new space. As the transformation is implicit you do not know the link with your original features.

Comment: Actually, the `dual_coef_` is product $\alpha_i y_i$.